# Get Instagram photos, count of likes and comment on website with jQuery or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, instagram

How can I get **all** **photos** and **count of likes and comments** of some instagram user into the website?

I tried many plugins or Instagram API, but nothing works.
The plugins are only for 12 photos and don´t give me count of likes and comments.
I need just some simple ajax request which give me urls of photos , likes and comments, but most importantly of **all posts** on Instagram account.

If anyone know how to do it or just give me hint where to find documentation of it, I will be thankful.

Thanks for your advices.

**EDITED**

I tried someting like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Instagram API</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="token-feed"></div>

<script>

    var token = 'SHORT-LIVED-TOKEN',       //there are my real values
        username = 'MY-USERNAME',          //there are my real values
        num_photos = 4;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {access_token: token, q: username},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + data.data[0].id + '/media/recent',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
                success: function(data2){
                    console.log(data2);
                    for(x in data2.data){
                        $('#token-feed').append('<img src="'+data2.data[x].images.thumbnail.url+'">');
                    }
                },
                error: function(data2){
                    console.log(data2);
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

But it shows me only this error:

[image]

Comment: I think the words _"The access token provided is invalid"_ have something to do with this.